# Expected value of the norm of a centered vector.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, random-variables

Let $X$ be a random vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\mathbb{E}[X]=0$. Is it true that $\mathbb{E}[ \|X\|]=0$ ? (Euclidean norm).

Comment: Norms are always non-negative, taking the value 0 iff their input vector is zero: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Definition

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**
Not true because
$$\left\|\vec{X}\right\| = 0 \iff \vec{X} = 0$$

In other words, for example, let the coordinates of $\vec{X}$ be distributed symmetrically, e.g. $\mathcal{U}(-1,1)$. Then what is the expected value?

But the Euclidean norm is
$$
\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n X_k^2}
$$
and $X_k^2 > 0$ a.s.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I can take in $\mathbb{R}$ the random variable $X$ in $\{-1,1\}$ with probability 1/2 each. then $|X|=1$ always.